# Handlebars: Problema de archivos estáticos (Static Files) - Nodejs, Express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, handlebars.js

tengo una web app de **nodejs** y **express** en el backend, y en el frontend tengo una plantilla (**html, css, js**). Utilizo como motor de plantillas **handlebars** en el proyecto.

Tengo un problema con mis archivos estáticos. 
En rutas como las siguientes funcionan bien los archivos estáticos

```
localhost:3000/cursos
localhost:3000/cursos/crear
```

Pero dejan de cargar los archivos estáticos cuando se llega a una ruta como la siguiente:

```
localhost:3000/cursos/editar/id
```

**server.js**

En mi archivo del servidor tengo configurado los archivos estáticos y el motor de plantilla (handlebars) de la siguiente manera:

```
const express = require('express');                
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');      
const path = require('path');

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
defaultLayout: 'main',
layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
extname: '.hbs',
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs'); 


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Entonces, no se a que se deba el problema :(
Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Falta información para poder ayudarte. ¿Te da algún mensaje de error en la consola del navegador? ¿Cuál? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tenía exactamente el mismo problema, el error radicaba en la manera en la que estaba cargando los archivos de la carpeta public (css, img, js, etc) en la plantilla de handlebars (archivos .hbs)

**Incorrecto:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

**Correcto:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

Al eliminar los **' ./ '** y **' ../ '** y reemplazarlos por **' / '** en las extensiones para buscar los archivos estáticos empezó a funcionar correctamente para todas las rutas.

**IMPORTANTE:**
No debes dejar la ruta sin el **' / '** inicial de lo contrario tampoco funciona.